# Arqadians or Arqanoids?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, top-7

When we refer to Arqade and all of our users, what do we call ourselves?

This is somewhat of an on going discussion.

Are we Arqadians or are we Arqanoids? Are we neither of these and in fact something completely different?

Comment: Arqaders. There you have it.

Comment: Arqaders is even worse than Arqanoids!

Comment: Makes both groups of supporters equally unhappy!

Comment: We can't have *you* happy, though!

Comment: @SaintWacko What makes you think I'm happy with Arqaders?

Comment: You suggested it. You would at least get some small satisfaction from having it chosen.

Comment: What about 'Gamers'?

Comment: wasn't posted as an answer, therefore I can't downvote it

Answer (score 16):

After [identify-this-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) was banned, the denizens of this site began their search for a new topic to argue about.  With nothing to have endless debates over, we were lost.

The **Arqadian vs Arqanoid** feud is there to satiate our ravenous appetite for pointless quarrels.  It is there as a fallback.  As long as it is left unresolved, we can feed on the triviality forever.

Do not collapse the waveform.  Do not take away our food source.  We hunger.

Comment: Wise words, robot.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: @kalina It's not an answer because the question is not constructive.

Comment: [I have unreasonably strong opinions on this largely irrelevant topic and will delete my account if we chose the option I do not prefer](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7781531#7781531)

Comment: @BenBrocka stop making me laugh at work, it makes it so obvious I'm not working.

Comment: @kalina status-declined

Comment: *cry*... 10 more to go...

Comment: I agree with the robot.  A community must have something to argue about in order for it to remain healthy, and I feel a trivial matter where no feelings (other than @BenBrocka's) will get hurt is the best type of arguement.

Answer (score 0):

We are Arqadians.

Who must put at least 30 characters in an answer.